# react conditional rendering data

Tags: reactjs, api, rendering

I have a problem with maping. When i'm trying to get more than 6 objects i get an error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'thumbnail')", even if i get full response from console.log.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Box, Typography } from '@mui/material'
import { LoadingNewsData, NewsData } from '../context/CryptoContext'
import NewsBlock from '../components/NewsBlock'

const News = () => {

  const loadingNews = LoadingNewsData()
  const news = NewsData()

  let allNews;

  if (!loadingNews) {
    allNews = news.slice(0, 10)
    console.log(allNews)
  }

  return (
    <Box width="80vw">
      <Box
        height="7vh"
        display='flex'
        alignItems="center"
        justifyContent="center"
        backgroundColor="var(--nickel)"
      >
        <Typography
          fontSize="30px"
          color="var(--silver)"
          fontFamily="var(--main-font)">
          Today's News
        </Typography>
      </Box>
      {!loadingNews &&
        <Box display="flex" flexWrap="wrap">
          {allNews.map((news) => {
            return (
              <NewsBlock key={news.datePublished} sourceLogo={news.provider[0].image.thumbnail.contentUrl} source={news.provider[0].name} category={news.category} title={news.name} link={news.url} image={news.image.thumbnail.contentUrl} />
            )
          })}
        </Box>}

    </Box>
  )
}

export default News
```

Comment: Please, show your data, especially a 7th object.

Comment: the error means that at some point `thumbnail` is `undefined` which in this case the object number 7 probably. try to do an [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) before reading `thumbnail`. for example: `sourceLogo={news.provider[0].image?.thumbnail.contentUrl}`

Comment: @mocherfaoui your point is valid, but to be clear - it means that you try to do `undefined.thumbnail`, it doesn't say anything about `thumbnail` being `undefined`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski you're 100% right, it can be that `image` is `undefined`, thanks for the heads up